# addEntity is not working with self join

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Can any one tell me why addEntity is not identifying separate column from alias? Both parent and child getting child value only. parents field is getting override by child filed.

If I keep `pr.* first` in select statement then it take parent value in both object.

My code is as below.

```
String sql="select ch.*,pr.* from users as ch inner join users as pr on ch.parent_id=pr.id";
```

Query

```
query=session.createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity("ch",UserDTO.class).addEntity("pr",UserDTO.class);

List<Object> result=query.list();  

Object[] objects = (Object[])result.get(0); 

UserDTO child=(UserDTO)objects[0];

UserDTO parent=(UserDTO)objects[1];
```

I have read this doc [hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13763), it is suggesting to use as follow.  But {} is not working in mysql select.

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT {cat.*}, {mother.*}  FROM CATS c, CATS m WHERE c.MOTHER_ID = c.ID")
 .addEntity("cat", Cat.class)
 .addEntity("mother", Cat.class)
```

Comment: It works for me select {ch.*}, {pr.*}, i use hibernate 4.3

Comment: Yes, I am was using it wrongly,  Finally it work for me also.

Comment: Query uery=DB.currentSession().createSQLQuery(sql.toString()).addEntity("cr",ConnectionRequestDTO.class).addEntity("fu", UserDTO.class).addEntity("tu",UserDTO.class).addEntity("m", MessageDTO.class).addEntity("qs", QueenShareDTO.class).addEntity("ms", MerchantShareDTO.class).addScalar("messageCount").addScalar("lastMessage");

Comment: I was using addEntity instead of "addScalar" .

Comment: Hey @PiyushAghera how did you fix this error? I'm facing the same problem. I'm doing a self join and the order I put the .addEntity results in unwanted results. I'm using Hibernate 5.1. Thanks